# Intermitently lossing touchpad and cursor

Tags: touchpad, cursor, firmware, tpm, inode

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

From time to time the cursor disappears and I cannot get it back and the system doesn't respond to the touchpad either.

The only way I can get around this is to reboot.

Whenever I boot I get:

[      1.079644] tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead

Which may or may not be related.

Sometimes I also get:

/dev/nvme0n1p2: recovering journal

Followed by several lines similar to:

/dev/nvme0n1p2: Clearing orphaned inode 9967976 (uid=1000, mode=0100664, size=34201)

and variations of this for various inodes.

If the inode info is critical and someone can tell me where I can find it as a log rather than me trying type it in from a video I'll post it.

Thanks.

Comment: This error and all the ones following are due to the system cleaning up and are normal. /dev/nvme0n1p2: recovering journal If you do not do a proper shut down files are left open and the system has to take care of it on boot.

Comment: Thanks David.
When you say "This error" I presume you mean "/dev/nvme0n1p2: recovering journal" and everything that follows, Or do you mean everything, including "Firmware Bug"?

Comment: Not firmware bug